# Make sober plots with matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm plotting some transfer function with matplotlib and seaborn.

This is  the format I'm making the plots so far:

[image]

[image]

It gets somehow messy, I will prefer to make the plots similar to this one:

[image]

Showing the y-label Vo/Vi vertically, with rows t the end of the axes and only showing only the peak values of the curve.

There is a preset style in matplotlib or seaborn to get this kind of plots?

Comment: Not a preset solution, but you can use the same techniques from here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17690294/1867876

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following should work:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = [0, 1, 2, 3]
y = [0, 1, 2, 3]
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.ylabel('$\\frac{V_i}{V_o}$', rotation=0, size=25)
plt.xlabel('$D$')
ax = plt.gca()
ax.set_yticks([max(y)])
ax.set_xticks([max(x)])
plt.hlines([max(y)], 0 ,max(x), linestyles='--')
plt.vlines([max(x)], 0, max(y), linestyles='--')
plt.axis([0, 4, 0, 4])
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: To get even closer to your wanted result you can get rid of the right and top spines using plt.gca().spines['top'].set_visible(False)